# Multiple MySQL selects

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a query but I want to add another field to it from another table...

This is what I am using now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tournaments t , tournament_participants t1 
WHERE t.tournament_id = t1.tournament_id 
ORDER BY t1.tournament_id, t1.team_id;
```

This works fine, but I also want to get the team name from the team table using the `team_id` as part of this query...

I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: Really it depends on the way your tables are structured though. Looking at your query how does one think what sort of refrential integrity is used within? :) Should assume that participants table have a foreign key referencing to taeam table? It's a good practice to provide your table schema and at least some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using joins:

```
SELECT * FROM tournaments AS t 
LEFT JOIN tournament_partecipants AS tp ON t.tournament_id = tp.tournament_id 
LEFT JOIN team ON tp.team_id = team.team_id 
ORDER BY tp.tournament_id, tp.team_id
```

Comment: This last one gives me what I wanted, thanks...

The others do but this one gives me only the data I wanted..

The help is much appreciated, guess I am now going to have to learn about joins :)

Thanks again everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT t.*, t1.*, t2.name 
FROM tournaments t 
INNER JOIN tournament_participants t1 ON t.tournament_id = t1.tournament_id
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t1.team_id  = t2.team_id 
ORDER BY t1.tournament_id, t1.team_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.. the last one actually gives me what I wanted, the rest do but with more data..

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what sort of table schema you have. Following query is based on lots of assumptions. So I may be wrong to what you really need. Please take a look at it.

Query:

```
select p.pid, p.pname, t.id as teamID
from participants p
left join tournament tt
on p.ttnid = tt.tnid
inner join team t
on tt.tnid = t.ttid
```

Results:

```
PID     PNAME   TEAMID
1       john    10
2       tim     10
3       alex    20
4       ron     20
5       kate    30
```

Reference: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c2f/2)

Please let us know if you require any different solution or further clarification :)